# Which Stack Exchange site to post an OS installation problem

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am curious as to what SE I should post this question on:

> I am trying to reformat my Alienware M15x laptop which has a aftermarket graphics card installed (NVidea Geforce 675m).
>
> No matter what OS I try to install, as soon as I get past the first part of the installation and it tries to actually start up the OS, the screen is white and I cannot do anything.
>
> How can I fix this? I have an exam tomorrow and need this fixed before then!

Comment: IMHO, this isn't a duplicate question, because NONE of the sites mentioned in the answer to the linked post are appropriate for an installation problem!  See the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask on [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com)

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about
>    - computer hardware,
>    - computer software, or
>    - personal and home computer networking